# Right way to use Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics-api

Has anyone worked with GA API? I want to make a custom report on my web application by pulling data from my Google Analaytics Account. This may include pulling goals and conversions data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible but its a little tricky.

You can test what I am talking about here:  http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

**Restricted dimension and metric combinations:**

If you check the [Dimension and metric reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=goal_conversions,visitor). next to each of the dimensions and metrics there you can check them on and off.  If you check under the Goals conversions group you will notice that when you select some of them you are no longer able to select other ones.  So you will have to decided exactly what data you need and are allowed to request from the API.

**XX in the metrics**
If you check some of the goal metrics you will notice that they have an XX in them.  The xx must be replaced with the goal number that you wish to select out.  For example: ga:goalXXStarts would become ga:goal1Starts

**List of all goals**
If you need to get a list of all of the goals you will find that in the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtGoalGuide) not the core reporting API.

I hope this helps.